# Was Goggle.com actually crazy malware in 2006?

Tags: malware, virus, internet, historical, typosquatting

This video shows how somebody accidentally opens Goggle.com instead of Google.com. He gets flooded with pop-ups, *SpySheriff* or *SpywareSTOP* get installed automatically, and the computer user has no chance of closing the seemingly hundreds of pop-up windows:

- [McAfee version: “Spyware
  Rubbernecking”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3atmWmWCwlw)
- [WebRoot version: “The effects of
  typosquatting”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6D-GSdLtNo)

The Wayback Machine, unfortunately, excludes Goggle.com, Goggle.net and Goggle.org for unknown reasons.

Did this crazy pop-up flooding malware actually exist in 2006?

Comment: Well typosquatting has existed since at least the early 1990s, probably earlier.

Comment: First, this is not a "malware" but a typo squatting phish. Though the payload may download a malware. Second. `goggle` is simply a dictionary word.  Third, wayback machine will try to remove most javascript to prevent dangerous redirect.   Fourth  : typo squatting phishing is an on going `business`.

Comment: Sometime domain registrar may delete or put the typo squatting domain into a blacklist sinkhole.  By the way, malware researcher are never short of those sample, as long as you know how to create a honeypot to collect those stuff or exchange it within the researcher group.

Comment: Every day hundreds of spam sites are created *just for this*. They have already used things like `apple.com` but with a cyrillic `a` (which in practically all fonts looks indistinguishable to the human eye...). It has been used to trick developers to download malware infected opensource packages (both by typosquatting the repository domain or simply uploading a typosquatted package to the repository).

Comment: [`whitehouse.gov`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehouse.gov) vs. [`whitehouse.com`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehouse.com), blah.

Comment: @neverMind9 The reason is because of the robots exclusion standard. The web archive has the questionable practice of retroactively removing a site from its archive if a _new_ site with the same domain excludes the bot from archiving it. So in other words, I can register an old, dead domain that was archived and create `/robots.txt` that excludes everything, and the archived version of the site will be censored.

Comment: What is the Wayback Machine?

Comment: @Evorlor historical archive of many webpages at various points in time. https://web.archive.org. it's frickin _dope_ and saves me from 404 pages all the time.

Comment: Well, that's what NoScript plugins were mostly used for.

Comment: @Forest No, it does not say “due to Robots.txt” but “this page has been excluded”, which means that **even if it is allowed by robots.txt, it is inaccessible.**

Comment: @Evorlor On the Wayback Machine, you can see older revisions of webpages it crawled.

Comment: @neverMind9 Oh interesting. Well that I don't have an explanation for.

Comment: @strugee I agreed. But sometimes, there is Robots.txt and manual exclusion.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6D-GSdLtNo Video statistics: Doubled view counts due to this question.

Comment: The selection criteria for the Wayback Machine are such that sites which never attracted significant links from other sites are unlikely to be included.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Let me summarise what you are seeing:

- someone navigates to a typo-squat site (goggle.com)
- the browser is then flooded with numerous pop-ups, warning windows, etc.
- eventually, the anti-virus starts to detect malware
- the machine crashes

It is difficult to think that there are young technology professionals now for whom that sequence is new and strange. For those of us browsing the Internet in 2006, this was a reality. I experienced this, myself, more times than I could count.

To answer your question, this was neither crazy nor limited to this one site.

The malicious (or hacked) website was coded to flood the user with ads and legitimate-looking Windows warning windows. When the user tried to close the windows, dozens more sprouted until the machine crashed. For many people, events like this are what got them familiar with the Windows Task Manager, which was the only way to prevent a total machine meltdown.

The warning windows were, in fact, browser windows, and when you interacted with them, it translated the user's click into an "OK" for installing something. That's how the viruses got installed.

So, these little gems crashed your machine (causing a reboot) and installed all manner of viruses. It was sometimes impossible to remove them without "nuking from orbit".

Many layers of security now exist in browsers to prevent that type of problem (although the attackers continue to evolve). Pop-up blockers, now standard, was the first thing to be used on the browser side. UAC was one of Windows first attempts to block this sort of application behavior from the OS.

Comment: Thank you for making my day complete by making me feel very old ... Was 2006 and all this stuff 12 years ago??

Comment: Where can I get this kind of pop-up malware for experimentations today?

Comment: @neverMind9 i could think about any pron site. But the Problem, you must use a very outdated Browser and maybe OS to see them nowadays

Comment: It's not malware but HTML code. Look for "pop-up ads" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-up_ad and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adware

Comment: This is also partially the source of the pop-culture representation of "getting a virus" being a million popups appearing everywhere. I think that even this aspect may be aging out since I seem to remember more pop culture references for ransomware than popup floods recently (though I can't think of specific examples)

Comment: I never got that stuff, maybe because I could tell it was browser windows.

Comment: The real issue would occur with frameless browser windows. Was such kind of oversight available in 2006? I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Back then we had a lot more trust of programmers... Microsoft, at one point, tied Windows Update to their browsers via something called ActiveX, which lets people format computers via a webpage.  It's pretty crazy.

Comment: @Nelson Which webpage does format my HDD?